# Is it a good approach to duplicate data in a database?

Tags: mysql, database-design, denormalization

I have a program that needs to store *traceroutes* (among other data).

Here is a diagram that depicts the business scenario:

[image]

My use case right now is to store the *traceroutes* using the following tables (with their corresponding columns):

**packet**

```
packet_id
source_ip
destination_ip
packet_length
```

**traceroute**

```
traceroute_id
packet_id
timestamp
path_id
```

**path**

```
path_id
traceroute_id
timestamp
```

**ip**

```
ip_id
ip_address
```

**path_ip**

```
path_id
ip_id
order_index
```

This creates the need to make several `JOINs` to get back a `traceroute`, but it makes the pieces of the `traceroutes` available for query for other needs.

I am considering having a second `traceroute` table that stores the `path` as a json string of `ip_addresses`. This allows me to recover full `traceroutes` with minimal `JOINs`, but still retain the individual hops (`ip_addresses`) used for other queries.

**My questions are**:

1. Does having this duplicated data make sense?
2. Is there a better approach to this?

**Responses to comments:**

I would add the `traceroute` data from one method, and would populate the tables at the same time.

The duplicated table (perhaps called `traceroute2`?) would just be used for retrievals, and none of the data would ever be edited or updated.

I am considering this because I am most interested in speed of data retrieval. I did some benchmarking (sort of crude) and I can get a 2-6X speed improvement on retrieval.

I don't want to prevent `JOINs` for a particular reason, just want to avoid this many. For this operation, I never need the individual hops of a `traceroute`, so I don't see what I would gain by splitting them out when I add it, and then piecing them back together again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De-normalisation and certain kinds of data duplication can be a convenient way to speed-up processes. Examples are caching, datawarehousing, and materialised views.

Meanwhile the duplicated data is relied upon as a read-only snapshot (i.e. point-in-time copy of the actual data), or the system can guarantee consistency (like in the case of caches), it is safe to rely on this practice.

Answer (score 0):

On the JSON question...  Look at the `SELECTs` you will be performing.  If any of them need to search (`WHERE`) or sort (`ORDER BY`) on a particular field, then expose it as a column, probably with an `INDEX`.  Otherwise, consider throwing it into a JSON column.

At one extreme, all the info could be in a single table with (id, src_ip, dst_ip, timestamp, json).

Even more extreme...  Instead of the json column, you could simply have a text column containing the raw output of traceroute.  That is, if all you are going to do is echo the original output, why unpack and repack it?